# Sending emails with laravel5.0 error SSL

Tags: php, email, ssl

I am try to send an emails with gmail and laravel and I don't recieve any errors but I don't send the email.

The code of  mail.php

```
<?php
return[
'driver'=>env('MAIL_DRIVER','smtp'),
'host'=>env('MAIL_HOST','smtp.gmail.com'),
'port'=>env('MAIL_PORT',587),
'from'=>['address'=>'emaiL@gmail.com','name'=>'Md. Ainul Moin Noor'],
'encryption'=>'tls',
'username'=>env('MAIL_USERNAME','email@gmail.com'),
'password'=>env('MAIL_PASSWORD','pwd'),
'sendmail'=>'/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend'=>true,
];
```

And the .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=pwd
```

Could anyone helps to me ? I try to change to ssl and i can't send the email.

Comment: Can you send an email from that host? Not by PHP I mean

Comment: I try this in localhost , I supose that is an specific configuration in a file output of the project.

Comment: Please can you post your full code to send the email, that's only the configuration and it is wrong you can't do `return[...]`

Comment: I have this configuración , I supose I have wrong

Comment: So can you post your full code or aren't you interested anymore on this?

Comment: This is my code in mail .php , I will find more information about this.